# Can I add a string type parameter to a SQL statement without quotes?

Tags: c++, sql, oracle11g, c++builder

I have a C++Builder SQL Statement with a parameter like

```cpp
UnicodeString SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (DATETIME) VALUES (:dateTime)"
```

Can I add the parameter *without* quotes?

Usually I'd use

```cpp
TADOQuery *query = new TADOQuery(NULL);
query->Parameters->CreateParameter("dateTime", ftString, pdInput, 255, DateTimeToStr(Now()));
```

which will eventually produce the SQL String

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (DATETIME) VALUES ('2022-01-14 14:33:00.000')
```

but because this is a legacy project (of course, it always is) and I have to maintain different database technologies, I need to be able to inject database specific date time conversion methods, so that the endresult would look like

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (DATETIME) VALUES (to_date('2022-01-14 14:33:00.000', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')))
```

If I try injecting this via my 'usual' method (because I don't think I can inject a second parameter into this one) it'd look like:

```cpp
TADOQuery *query = new TADOQuery(NULL);
query->Parameters->CreateParameter("dateTime", ftInteger, pdInput, 255, "to_date('" + DateTimeToStr(Now()) + "', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')");
```

but of course the result would look like:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (DATETIME) VALUES ('to_date('2022-01-14 14:33:00.000', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')'))
```

and therefore be invalid

Or is there another way to do this more cleanly and elegantly? Although I'd settle with 'working'.

I can work around this by preparing two SQL Statements and switch the statement when another database technology is but I just wanted to check if there is another way.

Comment: Does C++Builder really take a parameterized query and then replace the parameter with a string? If it does then that seems like a very bad library to be using as it should just pass the parameterized SQL string and bind in the parameter values.

Comment: @MT0 it does pass the parameter bindings to the database engine. It is the engine that ultimately produces the SQL in the proper formatting that it wants. That is one of the benefits of using parameterized queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you defining the parameter's `DataType` as `ftInteger` when your input value is clearly NOT an integer? You should be defining the `DataType` as `ftDateTime` instead, and then assigning `Now()` *as-is* to the parameter's `Value`. Let the database engine decide how it wants to format the date/time value in the final SQL per its own rules.

```cpp
query->Parameters->CreateParameter("dateTime", ftDateTime, pdInput, 0, Now());
```

Comment: That was a typo, I meant to write ftString.

Will this still work if the database engine is agnostic to the database technology? There are three databases in production environments, all connected via an ODBC driver and so far I haven't found any way to tell the database engine which technology is underlying.

Comment: @Tigerplush "*I meant to write ftString*" - that would still be the wrong type to use if the actual column is a date/time type and not a string type. "*Will this still work if the database engine is agnostic to the database technology?*" - yes, when used correctly. "*There are three databases in production environments, all connected via an ODBC driver and so far I haven't found any possibility to tell the database engine which technology is underlying.*" - you don't need to.